# Download multiple remote images via zip

Tags: php, http, zip, imagedownload

I need to create a function which creates a zip download consisting of a variant number of remote images which are being displayed on a website. The language on the server is in PHP but have a access to a Azure VM which could act as a controller if necessary. What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to do that just fine. You just need to use [`Zip`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php). That link is to the main doc page for `Zip`.

[Here's a tutorial on how to use PHP's Zip](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php), and here are [some `Zip` examples on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php).